# PHP MYSQL ODBC connection succesfull but not retrieving data

Tags: php, odbc

so i moved all the data from mysql control center(outdated) to workbench

all the connections seems to be successful but i cant retrieve any data while loggin in.its blank page..was working before i migrated everything over

see the code and screenshot below..any help would be appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quiNX.jpg)

```
 include('dbconnect.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $error_username = '';
    $error_password = '';
    $error_general = '';

    $usernamedd = $_POST['username'];
    $passworddd = $_POST['password'];

    if($usernamedd == '')
        $error_username = '<font color="red">- No username entered</font>';
    if($passworddd == '')
        $error_password = '<font color="red">- No password entered</font>';

    if($usernamedd != '' && $passworddd != '')
    {
        //echo "SELECT username,firstname,lastname,perm_calendar,perm_users,perm_market,perm_newsletter FROM emp_tbl WHERE username='$usernamedd' AND password='$passworddd'";
        $result = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT username,firstname,lastname,perm_calendar,perm_users,perm_market,perm_newsletter,perm_topagents FROM emp_tbl WHERE (username='$usernamedd' OR email='$usernamedd') AND MD5(password)=MD5('$passworddd') LIMIT 1");

        //echo "SELECT username,firstname,lastname,perm_calendar,perm_users,perm_market,perm_newsletter FROM emp_tbl WHERE username='$usernamedd' AND  MD5(password)=MD5('$passworddd') LIMIT 1";

        //echo "SELECT username FROM staff WHERE username='$username' AND dept='Admin'<br><br>";
        $_username = odbc_result($result, "username");
        $_fullname = odbc_result($result, "firstname").' '.substr(odbc_result($result, "lastname"),0,1).'.';
        $_perm_calendar = odbc_result($result, "perm_calendar");
        $_perm_users = odbc_result($result, "perm_users");
        $_perm_market = odbc_result($result, "perm_market");
        $_perm_newsletter = odbc_result($result, "perm_newsletter");
        $_perm_topagents = odbc_result($result, "perm_topagents");

        //echo "<br><br>username: ".$_username;
        //echo "<br>full name: ".$_fullname;
        //echo "<br>perm_calendar: ".$_perm_calendar;
        //echo "<br>per_users: ".$_perm_users;
        //echo "<br>perm_market: ".$_perm_market;
        //echo "<br>perm_newsletter: ".$_perm_newsletter;

        if($_username != '')
        {
            if(isset($_POST['save']))
            {
                setcookie("username",odbc_result($result, 'username'),time()+604000);
                $resultlog = odbc_exec($conn, "INSERT INTO logs_login (date, file, username, pwd, description, type, ip) VALUES (NOW(), '$file', '$usernamedd', '$passworddd', 'Success : 7 days', 'login', '$ip')");
            }
            else
            {
                setcookie("username",odbc_result($result, 'username'));
                $resultlog = odbc_exec($conn, "INSERT INTO logs_login (date, file, username, pwd, description, type, ip) VALUES (NOW(), '$file', '$usernamedd', '$passworddd', 'Success : Browser Session', 'login', '$ip')");
            }
            $_username=odbc_result($result, 'username');
            $logged_in = 1;

            header("Location: admin_directory.php");
        }
        else
        {
            $logged_in = 0;
            $error_general = '<font color="red">- No such user or invalid password</font>';

            $resultlog = odbc_exec($conn, "INSERT INTO logs_login (date, file, username, pwd, description, type, ip) VALUES (NOW(), '$file', '$usernamedd', '$passworddd', 'Failure: Incorrect user/pwd', 'login', '$ip')");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check if your migration is successful and complete, where did you migrate

Comment: yes i can see all the tables and data